# Possible to edit point cache data for cloth simulation using python?

Tags: python, cache

Is it possible to manually edit the baked positions of points in a cloth simulation point cache using python?

I found this:

> For most simulations the point cache can be stored either in memory (default) or on disk. Memory caching is very fast and enables editing of the baked data,

[Source](https://code.blender.org/2011/01/a-look-at-point-cache/#the-new-improvements)

What does "editing of the baked data" mean here?